# Finding highs and lows between lower and upper limit on Stochastic

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create Stochastic Divergences and I don't really like the available open source scripts. The question is how do I obtain the highs and lows below 30 and above 70 lower and upper limits only? That way I could compare them to their price above and there we go with the divergences. I'm not really interested in what's between those limits because it's inaccurate. Most of the scripts are using fractals, but I want specifically the outer highs/lows. Could you please share your experience on how to find those?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use something like this:

```
//@version=4
study("")
s = stoch(close, high, low, 20)
hi = highest(s > 70 ? s : na, 50)
lo = lowest(s < 30 ? s : na, 50)
plot(s)
plot(hi, "hi", color.green, 2, plot.style_circles)
plot(lo, "lo", color.red, 2, plot.style_circles)
hline(30)
hline(70)
```

[image]

Comment: How could I find the highest and respectively the lowest point from these tops/bottoms? Because there are multiple dots, I just need one of them for each top/bottom.

Comment: What would the reset condition be? You need the hi/lo since when? Currently, the hi/lo resets every time `s` is not in range.

Comment: I don't really know. I dont think fractals are usable in that case

Comment: If you're insterested in other ways of defining divergences, you may want to look at how I do it in here. Rather than identifying tops/bottoms, it uses a much simpler definition of what a divergence is, i.e., a discrepancy between the direction of the signal and price, and saves those levels as points against which further signal movement can be evaluated: https://www.tradingview.com/script/yG0rpNzO-Efficient-Work-LucF/

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it! I did something else https://pastebin.com/ULHSD4Pg. But how do I print it like actual lines, like these https://i.imgur.com/q72HWwv.png?

Comment: Have a look at the code from the "Divergence Indicator" built-in, or at this one, which uses line drawings: https://www.tradingview.com/script/n8AGnIZd-Divergence-for-Many-Indicators-v4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232201/discussion-between-nop-and-pinecoders-lucf).